# How to copy NTFS files that have a dot at the end of the filename

Tags: ntfs, copy

I am using MATE and Caja. I want to copy files from an NTFS drive to another NTFS drive.  When the copying process reaches a file which has a dot as the last character in the name (e.g. ABCD.) then I get an error message "Invalid Filename". Is there another way to copy these files?

Thank you.

Comment: It might help if you add information about how you are copying. eg the command used

Comment: WIN32 API strips trailing "." (dot). Therefore it depends on how exactly you copy and how you access the NFTS (smb mount, direct mount).

Comment: I am using Caja with copy and paste.  The files were created on a Win 10 laptop.

Comment: If the source and destination partitions are directly mounted then the cp command, run in a terminal, should work. Something like `cp -rpi /path/to/sourcedir /path/to/destination/
` will copy everything in and below sourcedir to destination. If a file already exists at the destination it will ask for confirmation to overwrite